# How to get the count of IDs in table 1 for current month which are also present in table 2 for current month or current month + 1 or current month + 2

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the count of IDs present in both tables 1 and 2 with the condition that the IDs present in table 1 for a particular month should match with the IDs present in table 2 for the same month or month + 1 or month + 2

I have tried writing a query in BigQuery but I am not able to get the count to cover 3 months from other table without hard-coding the months

The current tables look like below:

Table 1:
time_stamp | ID |

---

2019-06 |  1
2019-06 |  2
2019-06 |  3
2019-07 |  4
2019-07 |  5
2019-08 |  6
2019-08 |  7
2019-09 |  8
2019-09 |  9
2019-10 | 10

Table 2:
time_stamp | ID |

---

2019-06 |  1
2019-06 |  13
2019-06 |  8
2019-07 |  2
2019-07 |  9
2019-08 |  12
2019-08 |  4
2019-09 |  5
2019-09 |  13
2019-10 |  11
2019-10 |  6
2019-10 |  3

Expected Output:
time_stamp | count |

---

2019-06 | 2
2019-07 | 2
2019-08 | 1
2019-09 | 0
2019-10 | 0

The output for 2019-06 is 2 as the IDs 1 & 2 in Table 1 for 2019-06 are present in table 2 in either 2019-06, 2019-07 or 2019-08. Note that ID 3 from table 1 won't be included in the count for 2019-06 as it appears in table 2 after (2019-06 + 2) months

Comment: i am confused - accepted answer does not work for BigQuery!!!  based on question body and tag - I was expecting OP is looking for BigQuery related solution

Comment: I just modified the query to use corresponding BigQuery functions like EXTRACT(MONTH from time_stamp), EXTRACT(YEAR from time_stamp) and DATE_ADD() instead of the Month, Year and Dateadd SQL functions. The logic in the query was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this would accomplish your goal, although I wasn't able to test it out without a fiddle.

```
 SELECT timestamp,
       Max(id)
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   table2 t2
               WHERE  Month(t2.timestamp) IN ( Month(t1.timestamp), Month(
                                               Dateadd(mm, 1, t1.timestamp)
                                                       ), Month(
                                                       Dateadd(mm, 2,
                                                       t1.timestamp)) )
                      AND Year(t1.timestamp) = Year(t2.timestamp)
                      AND t1.ID = t2.ID)
GROUP  BY timestamp
```

Edit:

I initially read this incorrectly, and you were looking for counts. Same logic, different format.

```
 SELECT timestamp,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM   table2 t2
                          WHERE  Month(t2.timestamp) IN (
                                 Month(t1.timestamp), Month(
                                 Dateadd(mm, 1, t1.timestamp)
                                         ), Month(
                                         Dateadd(mm, 2,
                                         t1.timestamp)) )
                                 AND Year(t1.timestamp) = Year(t2.timestamp)
                                 AND t1.ID = t2.ID)
           THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS "count"
FROM   table1 t1
GROUP  BY id, timestamp
```

Comment: Wouldn't this show the count of all ID's in that month ? For example, in 2019-06, count of ID 1 is 2 (across both tables). However, there are IDs 1,2,3,13,8 for that month. So instead of 2, won't your query show 5 ? I think you will need to add a check for matching IDs as well.

Comment: Is the timestamp not the ID? Whoops, let's add an ID check. I had some difficulty reading the pseudo tables. Thanks for the callout, Gary. I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just replicate the data in the second table and use `count(distinct)`:

```
select timestamp_trunc(t1.time_stamp, month),
       count(distinct t1.id)
from table1 t1 join
     ((select t2.time_stamp, t2.id
       from table2 t2
      ) union all
      (select timestamp_add(t2.time_stamp, interval 1 month), t2.id
       from table2 t2
      ) union all
      (select timestamp_add(t2.time_stamp, interval 2 month), t2.id
       from table2 t2
      )
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and
        timestamp_trunc(t1.time_stamp, month) = timestamp_trunc(t2.time_stamp, month)
group by timestamp_trunc(t1.time_stamp, month)
order by timestamp_trunc(t1.time_stamp, month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT time_stamp, COALESCE(`count`, 0) `count` 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT time_stamp FROM `project.dataset.table_1`
) LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT time_stamp, COUNT(id) AS `count`
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.time_stamp, ARRAY_AGG(t2.time_stamp) matches
    FROM `project.dataset.table_1` t1
    JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
    GROUP BY id, time_stamp
  )
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UNNEST(matches) match
    WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', match) 
      BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', time_stamp) 
      AND DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', time_stamp), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
  )
  GROUP BY time_stamp
) USING (time_stamp)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data as it is in your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table_1` AS (
  SELECT '2019-06' time_stamp, 1 id UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10', 10 
), `project.dataset.table_2` AS (
  SELECT '2019-06' time_stamp, 1 id UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08', 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-08', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09', 13 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10', 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10', 3 
)
SELECT time_stamp, COALESCE(`count`, 0) `count` 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT time_stamp FROM `project.dataset.table_1`
) LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT time_stamp, COUNT(id) AS `count`
  FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.time_stamp, ARRAY_AGG(t2.time_stamp) matches
    FROM `project.dataset.table_1` t1
    JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
    GROUP BY id, time_stamp
  )
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM UNNEST(matches) match
    WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', match) 
      BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', time_stamp) 
      AND DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m', time_stamp), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
  )
  GROUP BY time_stamp
) USING (time_stamp)
```

with result

```
Row time_stamp  count    
1   2019-06     2    
2   2019-07     2    
3   2019-08     1    
4   2019-09     0    
5   2019-10     0
```